# Removed id_rsa unable to recreate passphrase

Tags: ssh

The other day I tried to make a new ssh key on my vps. For some stupid reason I removed the id_rsa file instead of just typing ssh-keygen -p
When I now try to use that command it asks me for the old passphrase, I hit enter like every tutorial tells me to do. But then it says "Bad passphrase" and I can't proceed.

What do I need to do to get a new ssh key?

Comment: `-p` is used to edit the passphrase of an existing private key, yet you've deleted that key... Just don't try to edit, create a new one using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (for RSA keys).

Comment: Ping @JohnWHSmith, just in case. (See above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-p` is used to edit an existing key. If you don't have a key already (or if you deleted it for some reason), there's no point in trying to edit it. Remove that switch in order to create a new key. Here's an example for an RSA key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```